# Need to create a report in Apache Kylin using SSB sample data

Tags: olap, olap-cube, kylin

I have just set up Apache Kylin 5.0 and have been playing around with the sample Data provided in the docker (DB: SSB). I have understood most of the concepts of Cubes, Dimensions, Indexes, Measures etc. but am stuck at a peculiar test report I need to create.

Scenario:
LO_ORDERDATE (Red outline in the image) is the date of the order
LO_COMMITDATE (Green Outline) is the date of Shipment. (Am assuming this, of course)
LO_QUANTITY (Yellow Outline) is the quantity of product ordered

Report Required
Daywise data of the sum of product ID x.
i.e. if product x is ordered in 50 quantity on jan 01 and commitdate is jan 31. And the same product is ordered in 100 quantity on jan 10 and the commitdate is jan 25. The data should show as follows

```
1-Jan   50
2-Jan   50
3-Jan   50
4-Jan   50
5-Jan   50
6-Jan   50
7-Jan   50
8-Jan   50
9-Jan   50
10-Jan  150
11-Jan  150
12-Jan  150
13-Jan  150
...
24-Jan  150
25-Jan  150
26-Jan  50
27-Jan  50
28-Jan  50
29-Jan  50
30-Jan  50
31-Jan  50
```

Is this possible using cubes?

I have tried using Calculated Column but I don't think they are meant for this type of scenario.

The same scenario can be imagined if I were to check daywise number of occupancy in a hotel if we have only the check-in date and check-out date in the reservation fact table.